# How do I solve this web page sign-in using J-script?

Tags: dom

I'm not very proficient with Dom manipulation coding and am trying to work out the following:

The following login page has 3 distinct entries, Username Email and password.
I want to add/change the following and do not know how to go about it.

- Code at current checks that every input is 10 characters or less -
  Change it so the email must be 20 characters long
- The password must be more than 8 characters and username 11
  characters long
- Check that the email contains the @ symbol
- Check the password contains at least 1 number, 1 character and 1
  special character
- Show a different error message per input field to show the user the
  reason the input was invalid

Here is the code ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    div {
      margin: 25px;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
    }
    .container {
      width: 300px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    button {
      display: inherit !important;
      margin: auto !important;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <label for="">Username</label><input type="text" id="Username" />
        <div id="userInfo"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="">Email</label><input type="text" id="email" />
        <div id="emailInfo"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="">Password</label><input type="text" id="password" />
        <div id="passwordInfo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
    let appData = {
      username: null,
      usernameMessage: "Username is too short",
      email: null,
      emailMessage: "Email too short",
      password: null,
      passwordMessage: "Password too short",
    };
  ​
    document.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
      appData[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
  ​
      if (
        appData[event.target.id].length > 0 &&
        appData[event.target.id].length < 20
      ) {
        document.getElementById(event.target.id + "Info").innerText =
          appData[event.target.id + "Message"];
      } else {
        document.getElementById(event.target.id + "Info").innerText = "";
      }
    });
</script>
```